# How to convert vcf to tbed/tfam and again convert it back to tbed/tfam to vcf using plink

Tags: plink

When converting vcf to tbed/tfam format, I am getting error like

```
unrecognized flag<'--transpose'>
```

Code I used:

```
plink2 --vcf sample_vcf_file.vcf --recode --transpose --out outputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct command is

```
plink2 --vcf sample_vcf_file.vcf --recode transpose --out outputfile
```

vcftools also can convert vcf into tped/tfam

Comment: Yep, from [plink manual](https://www.cog-genomics.org/plink/1.9/index): `--transpose Deprecated. Use "--recode transpose".`.